# VBA Runtime error 1004 opening a workbook with macros (Excel 365)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script which will unlock some protected cells in a collection of excel workbooks, and am getting that lovely elusive "1004" error. The workbook actually opens (so the path is valid), but comes up with this error somewhere afterwards, but still within the Workbooks.Open command.

Through various sources, I have tried various combinations of the following lines, but it always fails after the workbook has opened and before returning control to VBA (when stepping through).  Interestingly, it opens all the macro windows in the VBA IDE, but it doesn't highlight anything to indicate what should be the problem.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Workbooks.Open([[valid file name]], IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True,  Editable:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlNormalLoad, AddtoMRU:=False)
```

I'm not sure if its to do with macros and trusts, or with protected sheets, but apparently the application security line should have solved the first and CorruptLoad the second.  I'm sure there's some little thing I've missed - I just can't find it.

I've looked through the Workbooks.Open documentation online but there's no reference to protected sheets (CorruptLoad was gleaned out of a couple of different posts on people having similar-but-different issues).

Comment: Does the file you open have macros itself? Especially a `Workbook_Open` even? If yes please include the code of this event as the issue might be there and not in the code you show.

Comment: Hi, did you try to open this file manualy and check if it has checked the "Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model" [link](https://www.easeus.com/file-recovery/how-to-fix-runtime-error-in-excel.html)

Comment: Hi @p77u77n77k. This sheet will be opening a couple of hundred sheets in succession, so "Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model" will be a big chore.  The sheets were previously created with a VBA script and saved.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ - yes, this sheet does have macros. The only event-driven ones are for button clicks on the worksheet. and are all in the style of:
Sub AddCommentRowButton_Click()
    AddCommentRow AddCommentRowButton.TopLeftCell.Row
End Sub

and so should not be executed in the startup process.

Answer (score 0):

@p77u77n77k was definitely on the right track, and essentially answered the question. Ensuring that "Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model" is on certainly worked.  In the process of researching, I found this script which can programmatically turn it on, if needed.  Just one for the toolkit:
[Macro to Enable Trust](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/macro-to-enable-trust-access-to-the-VBA-project-object-model/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).